# What type of commercial aircrafts generate strong Wake Turbulence?

Tags: wake-turbulence

I know that 757, 737 generate strong Wake Turbulence and as pilots, we should always be aware of that and caution for the wake turbulence while landing and departing.

I would like to know if is there like a list of commercial aircraft based on their Wake turbulence generation?  Which one generate the most and which one generate the least? Let's assume they are all heavy, clean, slow!

Comment: I don't believe that the 737 is especially unusual but the 757 is often classified as "heavy" even though it's weight does not compare to a 747 for example.  It's supercritical wing can generate wake vortices that exceed those of the 747 in some flight phases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Big ones.

Wake turbulence is primarily proportional to the aircraft's weight, since this is generally directly related to the size of the aircraft and the amount of air the wings need to move to provide enough lift. Aircraft are categorized with respect to wake turbulence based on their maximum certificated takeoff weights. [FAA AC 90-23G](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_90-23G.pdf) describes classes for ATC purposes as follows:

- Super - Interim class for the A380 and AN225
- Heavy - 300,000 lb or greater
- Large - 41,000 - 300,000 lb
- Small - 41,000 lb or less

Heavy and Super category aircraft are required to add their category to their callsign when contacting ATC, e.g., "Speedbird 12 Super".

Aircraft in higher categories have larger separation requirements when in front on aircraft in smaller categories, such as between takeoffs or landings, and ATC will issue [caution messages cautionary advisories when required (Section 2-1-20)](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ATC.pdf).

The AC linked above discusses further on wake turbulence, such as how it propagates and how it should be avoided or escaped.

The FAA is also working on a [6 category system (A to F)](http://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/airline_operators/airline_safety/safo/all_safos/media/2012/SAFO12007.pdf), which is in effect at MEM, SDF, CVG, and ATL. [There are plans to expand this](http://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/airline_operators/airline_safety/safo/all_safos/media/2014/SAFO14007.pdf) to the Metroplexes of Houston, New York, Charlotte, Chicago, and Northern California in 2015.

> This approval was based on years of joint research and development by
>   the FAA, Eurocontrol, scientific experts in wake, and experts in
>   safety and risk analysis. Categories are now based on weight,
>   certificated approach speeds, wing characteristics, along with special
>   consideration given to aircraft with limited ability to counteract
>   adverse rolls.